# Joining 100 lists to make one big list

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a number of lists, labed s1,s2,s3,..,s100. And si(i=1,2,...,100) has different lengths and different coordinates. For example, the fist three lists are like

```
s1 = {{1, 1}, {1, 2}, {1, 3}, {1, 4}};
s2 = {{2, 1}, {2, 2}, {2, 3}};
s3 = {{3, 1}, {3, 2}, {3, 3}, {3, 4}, {3, 5}};
```

What I want to obtain is

```
{{1, 1}, {1, 2}, {1, 3}, {1, 4},{2, 1}, {2, 2}, {2, 3},{3, 1}, {3, 2}, {3, 3}, {3, 4}, {3, 5}};
```

In short, I want to make these coordinates in si(i=1,2,...,100) together, leading to one list. I know 'Join', it make two lists together. If I use 'Do', 'For' and so on, how to achieve it? Thank you.

Comment: Why did you not try `Join[s1, s2, s3]`?

Comment: Also `Flatten[{s1, s2, s3}, 1]`

Comment: @J. M. needs help  If the lists are too many, we can not  use Join[s1,s2,s3,s3,..,s100],.But I have tried loop commands('Do', 'For'), I still not obtain it.

Comment: @Bob Hanlon Thank you

Comment: You can use `Join` like this: `Join @@ {s1, s2, s3}`

Comment: If you have to keep 100 variables around, you're likely doing something wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
s1 = {{1, 1}, {1, 2}, {1, 3}, {1, 4}};
s2 = {{2, 1}, {2, 2}, {2, 3}};
s3 = {{3, 1}, {3, 2}, {3, 3}, {3, 4}, {3, 5}};
numberOfLists = 3;
Flatten[Join[Table[ToExpression["s" <> ToString[i]],{i, numberOfLists}]], 1]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

change `numberOfLists` to 100 or 1000 as needed. But I do not think it is a good idea to have so many variables `s1`, `s2` etc... You could design your data struct to avoid this. Use 3D matrix for example. Each page of the matrix is your `s`. This way you can iterate over pages of one variable of type 3D matrix instead of 100's of separate named variables.